# Visualize the navigation of robot in RVIZ?

Tags: simulation, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am developing a mobile robot. I have just created a basic program which moves the robot from one set of coordinates to another in a straight line. I publish the velocity of the robot in the /cmd_vel topic. I want to observe the effect on the robot of this program. So, I was thinking if it was possible to visualize the robot in RVIZ before I test it out in the real world. But, how to integrate RVIZ with my code so that when the program is run, I can see the robot moving in Rviz?

Very Urgent. If somebody could please help?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197031/visualize-the-navigation-of-robot-in-rviz?/) by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2014-11-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-11-08**:
I'm not sure that marking your question as urgent is likely to get answers any faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, read this:

http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide

Are there any nav_msgs/Odometry messages being published? They would be providing the pose of your robot. If so, you can open rviz, and in the left panel, click "Add," and then select "Odometry." Next, fill in the topic with the topic name of your robot. You can see its poses as it moves through space. If you want it to open automatically, you'll have to first save your rviz configuration somewhere, and then add this to your launch file:

```
<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d path/to/your/config/file"/>
```

If it's in your package, you can do this:

```
<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(find your_package)/config.rviz"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on 2014-11-08**:
Thanks. I would look up at it.